# Record iPad screen using Windows

Tags: windows, screen-recording, ipad-app

I know that QuickTime Player can be used on iOS to record iPad screen. But what about Windows? I found [Mirroring](http://www.mirroring360.com/) and it seems working (I failed to configure video resolution), but it's a trial version. Is there some free program to record iPad screen?

By the way, ideally I would like it to record taps on the screen like most windows screen recorders do with clicks, but this feature is not absolutely required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/247573/how-to-mirror-your-iphone-or-ipads-screen-on-your-windows-pc/) recommends [LonelyScreen](http://lonelyscreen.com/). I tried it today and it's really easy to set up. To record a screen, click the carat in the lower-right corner to open the recording toolbar, then click the big red button in the center to start recording. The video is saved as an MP4.

There's not a built-in option to show taps in LonelyScreen. [This guy](http://ryancollins.org/2013/08/30/how-to-record-touches-and-gestures-for-ios-screencasts/) suggests using Assistive Touch to show touches, which probably isn't what you had in mind. I tried it out in [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olXTe.jpg).

Comment: Recording works, but is it possible to configure video resolution? Now it is 960*720.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the resolution part. LonelyScreen is pretty bare-bones, so I doubt it. Maybe the resolution is determined by the window size?

Comment: Could you help with [adapting this solution for corporate network](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/36626/23135), please?

Comment: @Qwerity Sorry, I have only worked with SOHO networks. I don't have any experience with corporate networks. Your network admin should be able to fix it for you.